# Vanilla Android 4.4 OS, wired headset button as camera shutter

Tags: android, camera

I am using Nexus 4 and Nexus 5 with vanilla Android 4.4.4 OS.

I have a single-button wired headset and I want that its button works as a camera shutter.
By default when this headset is plugged in:

- a single click of the headset button does nothing.
- a long hold of the headset button launches voice input (similar to when you hold the Home button for a while, then swipe it to the top and tap the mic).

I know that the Volume hardware button works as a camera shutter. So I tried to bind my headset's button to Volume Up or Volume Down actions (with different apps from this list http://beebom.com/2013/07/5-apps-to-control-and-tweak-your-headset-buttons-in-android) but no luck: camera wouldn't take a picture but the volume level changes.

Any ideas here, guys?

PS Not to start a holywar and not sure if it helps but that worked out-of-the-box on my friend's iPhone 5 with this very headset.

Comment: Try http://android.stackexchange.com perhaps?